# Zoom in effect with css and jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I created an overhead map for a browser game I'm working on as a pet project.

I have a fixed size viewport div and an inner div which has all of my map icon elements inside.  I'm using jquery-ui to make the inner div draggable, but I'd also like to be able to give it a zoom effect with the mousewheel.

I've done some googling, but there don't seem to be any good solutions to the problem.

I tried this:

```
$('#map').bind('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function(e){
  if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta /120 > 0) {
    $("#map").css("width", "+=10");
  }
  else{
    $("#map").css("width", "-=10");
  }
});
```

but it's not doing anything, so I guess that I'm not binding to the right event. (Yes I'm running that jquery code inside of document(ready) )

Comment: I don't think you can perform increment and decrement operations within jQuery's `.css` function. I know you definitely can't do it with plain CSS.

Comment: The second example [in the article I wrote](http://css-tricks.com/controlling-css-animations-transitions-javascript/) might give you some insight for one way to do it. Only you'd have it start/stop on mouse zoom as opposed to buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  Here's the code for posterity:

```
$('#map').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e){
  //Get the transformation matrix from the css as a string. (it's named differently for different browsers)
  var scale = $(this).css('transform');
  scale = (scale == null ? $(this).css('-webkit-transform') : scale); 
  scale = (scale == null ? $(this).css('-ms-transform') : scale);
  //once we have the matrix, the scale is the first number, so parse the string to remove it.
  scale = scale.split(" ");
  scale = parseFloat(scale[0].substring(7, scale[0].length - 1));

  //e.originalEvent tells us how the mousewheel moves. (Also different for different systems)
  e.delta = null;
  if (e.originalEvent) {
    if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta) e.delta = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / -40;
    if (e.originalEvent.deltaY) e.delta = e.originalEvent.deltaY;
    if (e.originalEvent.detail) e.delta = e.originalEvent.detail;
  }
  //If delta is greater than 0, we're zooming in
  if(e.delta > 0) { 
    //5x zoom is the max that I want to zoom in.
    if(scale < 5) {
      //no need to re-form the matrix. specifying a new scale value will do the job.
      scale = ('scale(' + (scale + .1).toString() + ')');
      //update the transform css for each possible browser. 
      $(this).css({'transform':scale, '-ms-transform':scale, '-webkit-transform':scale });
    }
  }
  //if delta is less than zero, we're zooming out
  else{
    //for my purposes, I don't want to zoom out farther than the original map size
    if(scale > 1) {
      scale = ('scale(' + (scale - .1).toString() + ')');
      $(this).css({'transform':scale, '-ms-transform':scale, '-webkit-transform':scale });
    }
  }
```

Comment: edited to show the finished version which uses a css3 scale transform instead of changing width and height